# How to vertically align a 'span' in a 'div' with icon present?

Tags: css

I tried to vertically align a `span` in a `div` by css `line-height` and div `height`.
All works fine, but the center `span` shifts to the bottom when the `icon span` is added.
Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

```
  <span class="icon"></span>
```

**Failed at vertical align**
http://jsfiddle.net/9CJvm/

**Works fine without icon span**
http://jsfiddle.net/9CJvm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, you could add `vertical-align:middle` to the `span.icon` element:

The default value for the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`; thus the element was being aligned at the base of the parent element.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv3V5/)

```
.icon {
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url(https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/50264_300699565862_8082907_q.jpg);
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align:middle` for both `span.center` and `span.icon`.